# Defining lexical variable after defining subroutine

Tags: perl, subroutine

In Perl if you try to lexically declare variable with `my` after you declared a subroutine, this subroutine won't see this variable. However, subroutine declared after the variable will see the variable:

```
sub lol {
    if (@arr) {
        print "defined\n";
    } else {
        print "not defined\n";
    }
}
my @arr = (1,2,3);
sub lol2 {
    if (@arr) {
        print "defined\n";
    } else {
        print "not defined\n";
    }
}
lol; #prints "not defined"
lol2; #prints "defined"
```

However, if you set a variable without declaring it (`@arr = (1,2,3);`) or declare variable with `our`, both subroutines will see the variable.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: This part of your question: "However, if you declare if you set value to variable without declaring [...]" is hard to understand.

Comment: @asjo Oh, didn't notice, sorry, just corrected

Comment: Cool, much easier to understand now. If you "use strict; use warnings;" you'll have to declare all variables before using them, which will make it easier to avoid mistakes. It works as intended.

Comment: @asjo You don't have to declare them, but you do have to give the full package name, e.g. `$main::var`. When you use `my`, you do not have to specify package, because it declares a variable within the current scope.

Comment: @TLP much to my dismay, sometimes Perl really is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables which are not defined with `my` are implicitly `our` (global/package) variables. So it is a feature. `use strict;` pragma will force you to either use `our` or `my` explicitly in variable declaration.

To be more precise, quote from [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html#strict-vars)

> *strict vars*
>
> This generates a compile-time error if you access a variable that was neither explicitly declared (using any of my, our, state, or use vars ) nor fully qualified. (Because this is to avoid variable suicide problems and subtle dynamic scoping issues, a merely local variable isn't good enough.)

Comment: But both these subroutines and array are declared within the same scope, right?

Comment: `strict` does not force you to use `our` or `my`. It forces you to specify explicit package name. Unless the variable is declared in the current scope using `our` or `my`. Consider `perl -Mstrict -lwe'$main::x = 0;'`

Comment: @mpapec Subroutines inherit scope, right? Both subroutines and array are defined in the same scope, so array should be visible from both subroutines. I still don't understand why it is visible from only one subroutine.

Comment: @Vantuz Check [`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) page. `our has the same scoping rules as my or state, meaning that it is only valid within a lexical scope.` `lol()` can see global variable https://eval.in/231606 (but `strict` will complain if you enable it)

Comment: @mpapec Ok, I see, too make everything work I have to create alias for global variable in subroutine scope with `our`. But is there a way to define variable so as it would be visible for every subroutine called from the scope where it was defined without need for creating alias with `our`?

Comment: If you want to declare variable without our/my you most probably have XY problem.